# What are these rubber parts called in my audi s4

Tags: part-identification, audi, s4

Today I’ve made an upsetting discovery that mice have chewed up some rubber under my 14 ‘ Audi s4 hood. Two symmetrical pieces on both sides as well as the large rubber barrier in the middle. Please see images:

[image: rubber 1]
[image: rubber 2]

Can someone help me identifying those so I can try replacing them.

Comment: Be thankful that those are cheap - they could have chewed some very expensive bits.... Now get a cat...

Comment: This seems like a case of don't count your chickens before they hatch. You may have dodged a bullet or the other damage may not be obvious. My opinion is to solve your rodent problem before you start installing new parts.

Comment: @TimNevins Fair. I’ve installed mousetraps in my garage and tightened up my garage door seal.

Answer (score 4):

I'd talk to the dealer about a Raintray Hood Seal

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the part numbers are `8K0823721H` for the left seal and `8K0823722H` for the right seal.

**All** VAG (which includes Audi) parts have a 9 character (plus 1 char version identifier) part number, so if you remove the part, you will be able to confirm exactly what the part number is.

With the part number, you can go to `oemepc.com/audi` and put the part number in. That will show you all vehicles where the part was used and often link to an exploded part diagram with the part in it.

I found the likely numbers by browsing the Body section for the year of your S4 and finding [this page](http://www.oemepc.com/audi/part_single/catalog/au/markt/USA/modell/A4Q/year/2014/drive_standart/736/hg_ug/823/subcategory/823000/part_id/255871/lang/e)